# Can we use Sencha Touch to develop an application runs on Windows as Windows Application

Tags: windows, mobile, web, sencha-touch-2.1

I have to develop a project which runs on desktop(windows), web(browser) and mobile.I am planning to use Sencha Touch for mobile and web version of the project.

Can I use Sencha Touch to develop an application which runs on Windows OS as Windows application?

Please anybody can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Sencha touch can be used to develop on all three platforms.
The same application can be built into multiple platforms using cordova/phonegap. Using sencha touch, we can maintain a single code base and multiple apps .

And yes, you can package and publish it to windows store to run it as a windows application.

Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

Your all the requirements are fulfilled by Sencha Touch. Sencha touch apps runs on windows desktop/browser and mobile(native and web) also.

Ref: http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-with-windows-phone-8 , 
     http://www.sencha.com/blog/hello-sencha-touch-2-2/